# How to check if an array contains one thing or another

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, discord.js

I'm trying to make permission system on my Discord bot where it checks for a set permission value.

inside each command it contains this:
`permission: ['dev','mod','guildMod']`

I've tried using `x.permission.includes()` but it can only detect one of the values, I'm wanting to check through the array and seeing if it matches that permission or another permission that person has to execute the command.

**Edited:**

Inside my message.js event:

```js
let guildPerm = guildperms(message.member, 'guildMod');
if (cmd.permission.includes() && !guildPerm) {
    return client.responses('notAguildMod', message);
}
```

Inside my guildperms file:

```js
module.exports = (user, pledge) => {
    switch (pledge) {
        case 'guildAdmin': {
            return user.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR');
        }
        case 'guildMod': {
            return user.hasPermission(['MANAGE_CHANNELS', 'KICK_MEMBERS', 'MANAGE_ROLES', 'BAN_MEMBERS', 'MUTE_MEMBERS']);
        }
    }
};
```

The whole concept is to allow such as the developers, bot moderators/staff to execute that command regardless of if they have the `guildMod` permission.

Comment: it's not clear to me what behavior you desire. Can you elaborate? Ideally how an actual query and the result you'd like for the example you gave.

Comment: @ChristianFritz I've updated my question, if you would like to refresh yourself on the subject :)

Comment: I see you did add some code, but what are you trying to do/what's the bug of the existing code? Do you want the `hasPermission` function to check if the user has all the listed permissions?

Comment: The permissions are 'string' and has no relation to discord.js based permissions,
Each command is built with a set structure which contains `permission: ['dev','mod']` which is accessible via `cmd.permission` i want to be able to detect with permission that user has which is what `guildperms` acts as for `guildMod` perm.

Answer (score -2):

You can use: `Array.prototype.find()`

```js
const array1 = [5, 12, 8, 130, 44];
const found = array1.find(element => element > 10);
```